# How do I get sex from the woman in the village? (Murky Vaters)

Tags: the-witcher

I don't seem to be able to get the sex card for woman from the village.

What are the prerequisites? I tried to talk with the peasant women both right after entering the chapter and after completing most of the quests, but in both cases it just didn't happen.

Comment: This is a candidate for one of those well worded questions ... "How do I get sex from the woman in the village?" seems in line with a lot of the other witcher questions haha

Comment: This sounds a lot like a personal problem to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Advice on how to conquer the "hearts" of the women in The Witcher can be found in the spoiler checklist at [The Witcher Wiki](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Spoiler_Checklist).

Regarding the question at hand, since she asks for "something sweet"; you have to give her a sugar doll as present. Such a doll can be found throughout the game, or made for you by the local baker.

Comment: The problem is that she doesn't ask. I already spent hours searching and talking to all women at various times.

Comment: Ah, i see. If i understand correctly, the right "peasent woman" is wandering around in the village. Maybe this video can help you to locate her: http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/People_of_Murky_Waters#Video

Comment: I have already seen the video. There has to be some sort of trigger that enables, disables this discussion. What I'm asking is what this trigger is.

Comment: Then, unfortunately, i don't know what this trigger is. :-/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be triggered by the one and only NPC at a specific time of the day. I did manage to get it and it seemed pretty random :-/